# Java Binary Search Tree: Sum of all node's keys between min and max

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree, nodes

I was wondering if someone could help walk me through this problem for it really has me stumped.

You are given the root node of a binary search tree T and two integers min and max. Note that min and max are not necessarily stored in the tree. Determine the sum of all keys stored in T that are larger than or equal to min, and smaller than or equal to max. Implement your algorithm recursively. Clearly state base case and recursive step in your code.

This is what I have so far but it is overwhelmingly wrong.

```
/**
     *  Problem 2: Determine the sum of all node's keys between min and max (inclusive).
     */
    private static int problem2(Node root, int min, int max)
    {
        // Implement me!
         if (min == null) 
             return max; 
         if (max == null) 
             return min; 
         min.key += max.key; 
         min.left = problem2(min.left, max.left); 
         min.right = problem2(min.right, max.right); 
         return min;
    }
```

This is the node class

```
private static class Node
    {
        public Node left = null;
        public Node right = null;

        public int key;

        public Node(int key)
        {
            this.key = key;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `min` and `max` are `int`s, not `Node`s; why are you trying to use them like nodes?  And you've completely ignored `root`, the one actual `Node`; doesn't that seem odd to you?

Comment: The code posted does not even compile. What is your exact question ? I would recommend to start by a simply transverse over the entire tree. When you get this right think of the next step.